# How to understand the maxLik's result in r?

Tags: r, statistics

```
--------------------------------------------
Maximum Likelihood estimation
BFGS maximization, 49 iterations
Return code 0: successful convergence 
Log-Likelihood: -42669.88 
4  free parameters
Estimates:
      Estimate Std. error t value Pr(> t)    
[1,] -0.023648   0.001081  -21.87  <2e-16 ***
[2,]  0.129408   0.012860   10.06  <2e-16 ***
[3,] -0.650217   0.035436  -18.35  <2e-16 ***
[4,]  3.677548   0.046444   79.18  <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
--------------------------------------------
```

Here is my result of Maximum Likelihood estimation, I want to know how the maxLik calculate the 't value' and 'Pr(> t)' or the equation of  't value' and 'Pr(> t)'.

Comment: t = Estimate / Std.Error, for the probability you need the degrees of freedom.

Comment: Thank you. t value is a statistical concept? In parameter test or confidence interval? How can I kown more detail abou that?

Comment: You can learn more about this from any textbook about regression analysis.